# How do I select dynamic ids in this format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select dynamic ids when a user types something into the input fields. My app spits out the input fields in the following format:

```
<input id="student_1_first_name" />
<input id="student_1_last_name" />

<input id="student_2_first_name" />
<input id="student_2_last_name" />

<input id="student_3_first_name" />
<input id="student_3_last_name" />

etc.
```

For example, I tried doing this to select the end of the id string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
  function (){
    $("input[id$=_first_name]").bind("keyup", run_some_function_here);
    run_some_function_here();
    $("input[id$=_last_name]").bind("keyup", run_some_function_here);
    run_some_function_here();
  }
);
</script>
```

When I do that, Jquery can't seem to select the input ids, so the functions don't run. Do you have any ideas on how I can select the ids correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("input[id$=_first_name]")` looks like it should work.

Does this give them red borders?

```
$("input[id$=_first_name]").css({ border: '2px solid red' });
```

If it does, then the function is probably not being called properly. Are you using anonymous functions or passing a reference to an existing function?

### Update

Does this work as intended?

```
$("input[id$=_first_name]")
    .bind("keyup", function() {   run_some_function_here();   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response Alex. I'm passing a reference to an existing function. Your code does give them red borders, so I think it's an error with how I'm passing it to the function. I'll continue working at it now that I know where to look. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

assign class to each input e.g `<input id="student_1_first_name" class="input-class" />`

then try this

```
$(function() {
   $('input.input-class').each(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Puaka. Great suggestion. I'll try that too. Thank you so much.